# How to determine when a sensor's output signal changes significantly?

Tags: sensors, signal-processing, analog-sampling, data, algorithm

Starting with an analog signal from any sensor, how do I automatically determine if there is a real signal change or a reset? Below is the sample code that better explains my goal:

```cpp
value = sensorRead();

if (millis() > t + 1000) {
  value_old = value;
  t         = millis();
}
float d = value - value_old;
if (d < -3) {
  print("signal change")
  myfunction(); //ex. bink led
}
```

So if `value(current) = 0.5` and `value_old = 100` there has been a real change in signal, even if, because of noise, the value is not exactly 0.

It's very raw code, and I'd like to use a more professional approach that can detect both increments and decrements. Ideally, a suitable library, or alternatively a more efficient algorithm, would be ideal.

Comment: https://www.best-microcontroller-projects.com/arduino-absolute-value.html

Comment: you could average the reading over a period of time

Comment: `if (millis() > t + 1000) {` will run into problems about 49 days after arduino reset ... read this https://www.norwegiancreations.com/2018/10/arduino-tutorial-avoiding-the-overflow-issue-when-using-millis-and-micros/

Comment: The problem is not the millis(). The values are already filtered by a moving average, I want to distinguish the increments.

Comment: What do you know about the process's insignificant noise?  Do you care about drift?  E.g. would +0.1 per cycle be noteworthy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no simple and universal way of deciding what is to be
considered a “significant” change. My recommendation would be to create
an algorithm by playing with the data on your computer:

- Upload a sketch to your Arduino that simply reads the sensor and
  transmits the readings to your computer via `Serial`.
- Capture a long run of such readings in a file.
- Graph the readings and look carefully at the graphs: what would *you*
  consider a significant change? What criteria could you use to decide
  that a change is significant? Devise an algorithm to take this
  decision.
- Implement and test the algorithm on your computer, using the recorded
  data.
- Port the code to the Arduino.

Below are two examples that maybe could give you some ideas. First comes
the simplest I can think of: it says the change is significant if the
current value is far enough from a previously recorded value. That
recorded value is only updated after a significant change has been
detected.

```cpp
bool changed_significantly(int value) {
    const int change_threshold = 4;  // tune to taste
    static int old_value;
    bool changed = abs(value - old_value) >= change_threshold;
    if (changed)
        old_value = value;
    return changed;
}
```

It would be used like this:

```cpp
void loop() {
    int value = sensorRead();
    if (changed_significantly(value))
        Serial.println("Signal changed.");
}
```

Note that, with this algorithm, a very slow drift would periodically
trigger the detection of significant changes. If this is not what you
want, you may prefer to only detect changes that happen fast enough.
This can be detected by the use of a high-pass filter. The function
below implements a simple low-pass filter (exponentially weighted moving
average) and compares the current input to the previous output. The
difference is equivalent to a high-pass filter. If that difference is
large enough, a significant change is detected, then the filter is reset
in order to prevent it from being repeatedly triggered by a drift:

```cpp
bool changed_significantly(int value) {
    const float change_threshold = 4;   // tune to taste
    const float filter_constant = 0.1;  // this one also
    static float filtered_value;
    float delta = value - filtered_value;
    bool changed = abs(delta) >= change_threshold;
    if (changed)
        filtered_value = value;
    else
        filtered_value += filter_constant * delta;  // low-pass filter
    return changed;
}
```

---

**Edit**: some details about the filter.

This high-pass filter alone could be simplified as this:

```cpp
float filter(float x)
{
    static float y;
    float delta = x - y;
    y += filter_constant * delta;
    return delta;
}
```

Note that, if this function returned `y`, we would have a conventional
first-order low pass filter (exponentially weighted moving average).
Since it returns instead the difference between the input and the
previous low-pass-filtered value, it behaves as a high-pass filter. Its
transfer function is

H = (z − 1) / (z + k − 1)

where k is the filter constant. This constant is related to the cut-off
frequency as

f<sub>c</sub> ≈ k f<sub>s</sub> / (2π)

where f<sub>s</sub> is the sampling frequency. Note that, for
frequencies significantly smaller than the cut-off, the filter behaves
like a scaled derivative:

H x ≈ 1/(k f<sub>s</sub>) dx/dt

Comment: We don't deserve you Edgar!

Comment: Why would small drift over time trigger the first code? Is it because it accumulates over a long period of time? Basically, is it a math thing, or a programming issue?

Comment: @ZhelyazkoGrudov: It's the algorithm. The recorded value is only updated after a significant change has been detected. If there is a slow drift,  it will accumulate change until that detection is triggered.

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried your last function, and it works as desired, simple and effective!!!! I don't really understand the filter_constant function, how can I estimate the ideal value based on usage?

Comment: @boromyr: See expanded answer.